# Correcting the alignment changes while migrating from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I was working on a blog-site on Flask(Python), using Bootstrap 4. I was using Bootstrap 4 CDN, then when Bootstrap 5 came, I switched to Bootstrap 5 (local).

I am facing two issues.

1. On my navbar, Login & Register was "
   *right-aligned* ", now on Bootstrap 5 it is " *left-aligned* ".
2. On the responsive mobile layout, the menu button is not working.

If I just switch to Bootstrap 4, these two problems are not there.

How do I correct alignment in Bootstrap 5 ?

How do I make the menu button work on the responsive layout?

[What I want. ( note: this was on Bootstrap 4 )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqEbs.png)

[How it is. ( note: this is on Bootstrap 5 )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQqo0.png)

```
<header class="site-header">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">

    <div class="container">

      <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">Flask Blog</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">

        <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Navbar Right Side -->

        <div class="navbar-nav">
         {% if current_user.is_authenticated %} 
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('account') }}">Account</a>
         {% else %}
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a>
         {% endif %}
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your class `mr-auto` to `me-auto`
check out this page from bootstrap [spacing in bootstrap 5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/)

```
                <div class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a>
                </div>
```

[image]

Also as for your button not working you should make a slight change:
the change it to add  `bs` in between `data-toggle` and `data-target`

so it will be like this : `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target`

from:

```
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle"
                    aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
```

to:

```
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggle"
                aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
```

don't forget to take a look at the bootstrap documentation about [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/) and here is a working copy of your code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-beta1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">


<header class="site-header">

  <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">

    <div class="container">

      <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">Flask Blog</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>


      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">

        <div class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Navbar Right Side -->

        <div class="navbar-nav">
          {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('account') }}">Account</a> {% else %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a> {% endif %}
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.5.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-beta1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

if that didn't help let me know.